# How would you replace every instance of get_stylesheet_uri() with get_template_directory_uri()

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, parent-child

I am writing a wordpress child theme and I am looking replace every instance of get_stylesheet_uri() with get_template_directory_uri().

This is because the parent theme has declared all enqueues, image paths etc with get_stylesheet_uri and this means that the child theme looks in the child theme for these files.  The point of a parent is so that is can be updated easily without risk to the customisations in the child.  Short of copying the files (images, styles, scripts) manually to the child each update, I would like to write a function to ensure the correct path to the parent theme is used.

Currently, I am blocking parent styles by dequeueing them, then adding then enqueueing them again with the correct template function (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65523/how-do-i-dequeue-a-parent-themes-css-file)

but this does not work for images paths.

Comment: You could contact author of parent theme and ask to make theme child-theme compatible.

Comment: Thanks, I did and didnt really get a good reply.